# How often does DocSearch crawl a website

Tags: algolia

The [DocSearch site](https://community.algolia.com/docsearch/) says that once you sign up your documentation site will be crawled periodically. I'm wondering roughly how often that ends up being. Is it on the order of days, hours, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is indeed lacking on the website (but is given in the installation email you receive afterwards), every DocSearch instance is indexed once per day.